# Displaying your projects on portfolio - image or text?

Tags: ux-field, portfolio

I am a student designer who recently got on board of UX/UI design. I was wondering how you guys display your projects on your portfolio. I was exploring on behance and dribble, and it seems like some people like to show all of their work as a long image including all the texts, and others use images and texts separately. I understand that having an image display would allow more designer's freedom in terms of graphics and layout, but wouldn't this become hard to read based on different devices? also wouldn't this limit chances for their works showing up in search engines that gets the data based on texts (HTML)? Thank you and please let me know if my question is not clear!

Answer (score 1):

Your intuition is good.  Images containing excessive information are a usability nightmare.  The inner contents are neither reflexive nor responsive, they resist screen readers and other content crawlers, and they rarely look good except on the device they were designed on.

From a UX standpoint, good design means considering all of these factors, and putting in the work to make content effective and accessible in a variety of contexts.  An image might get the job done in a narrow way, but it's not a solution that demonstrates good practices.